# Getting form information in JSP using Apache Struts 2

Tags: java, validation, jsp, configuration, struts2

I'm learning Apache Struts 2 and I need help getting user input from a textfield.

**In my JSP I have:**

```jsp
<s:form action="login">
    <s:textfield label="Username" />
    <s:textfield label="Password" />
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

**In my Java file:**

```java
List<UserData> users = new ArrayList<UserData>();
private Map<String, Object> session;

public String execute() {
    addUser("SeyCC", "loop"); //@param Username, password
    session.put("user", users.get(0).getUsername());

    if(form info matches a username and password in list)
       return SUCCESS;

    return ERROR;
}

public void addUser(String username, String password) {
    users.add(new UserData(username, password));
}
```

My `UserData.java` just has two strings. One for username and one for password. My problem is the if statement you see. How can I get the username and password the user enters in the textfields and check the list to see if it's in there?

Comment: Do you have a `struts.xml`? The the form and its fields should be bound to an action when you submit them, otherwise it won't execute.

Comment: Yes, I have a struts.xml. Roman's answer answered my question. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to bind the textfields to the action

```jsp
<s:form action="login">
    <s:textfield key="Username" />
    <s:textfield key="Password" />
    <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

The `key` attribute can be used for `name`, `label`, `value`. See [`textfield`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/textfield.html) definition.

The action with name `login` should have a configuration mapping. Use this in `struts.xml` or you can use [configuration by convention](http://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html).

```java
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, Preparable {
  List<UserData> users = new ArrayList<UserData>();
  private Map<String, Object> session;

  /**
   * Field to store username.
   */
  private String username;


  public String getUsername() { return username; }

  public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }

  /**
   * Field to store password.
   */
  private String password;

  public String getPassword() { return password; }

  public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

  @Override
  public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session){ this.session = session; }

  @Override
  public void prepare() throws Exception {
    addUser("SeyCC", "loop"); 
  }


  public String execute() {

    if (!users.get(0).getUsername().equals(username) || !users.get(0).getPassword().equals(password))
       return ERROR;

    session.put("user", users.get(0).getUsername());

    return SUCCESS;
  }

  //@param username, password
  public void addUser(String username, String password) {
    users.add(new UserData(username, password));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The links really help as well.